# Graffle -Is there any way to force a connector to start from another point or follow a different path?

Tags: svg, raphael

Hi I'm trying to generate some diagrams using [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) together with [Graffle](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html) for the connections.
Now that problem I'm having is that these connectors apparently don't follow a certain path, they just join two objects without taking care that perhaps one line overlaps an object or that one line starts from the same point from where another line ends. This exactly my problem now.

[image]

In the above image, I need the line the connects the yellow and orange rectangles to start from another point perhaps from the mid-bottom point of the yellow rectangle. Here's a [fiddle](http://goo.gl/vnZY16) that shows what I'm talking about.

At first I thought I was doing something wrong in the diagram that I'm working on, but when I tried that very simple example on fiddle  I realized  that was the normal behaviour. That was why in a more complex digram I end up getting this result( Take a look a the connectors highlighted in yellow):

[image]

Is there any way I could get better connectors, similar to that the ones that [Bizagi](http://www.bizagi.com/) has (see the image bellow)?? or do I need to manually create those paths?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Wacky idea without coding, could you create another object as the joining element at the corners of the line in the pic, but make style them to be invisible ?

Comment: I don't think I quite understand you. Do you think you could explain your idea a little bit more in detail?

Comment: Here is a quick example of what I meant... http://jsfiddle.net/ka9sk2re/4/